# android custom view attributes not working after switch to gradle

Tags: android, attributes, gradle, android-custom-view

so I recently migrated to gradle now my custom view attributes return null

my project looks like this

--custom_icon_view // library that holds the custom view with custom attributes
--my application // this is the main app that actually uses the custom view

in my layout I have the namespace defined like this :

```
        xmlns:iconview="http://schemas.android.com/lib/be.webelite.iconview"
```

because using apk/res-auto retuns an error saying attibutes could not be identified

this is how I try to get the icon name defined in xml, this used to work perfectlly
but now it doesnt. and all I changed was migrating to gradle.

```
        final TypedArray a              = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,be.webelite.iconview.R.styleable.icon);
        icon_name = a.getString(be.webelite.iconview.R.styleable.icon_name);
```

so I'm guessing my gradle.build files are causing a problem?

I have the library set to

```
  apply plugin: 'android-library'
```

end the main app gradle.build as

```
  apply plugin: 'android'
```

this has been giving me headache for 2 days now :( any help/hints are very apperciated.

here are my gradle files

http://pastie.org/private/h57o8nanydosq0dtm6eiq

and here is the folder structure

http://pastie.org/private/nvbzomx2zeagdpzt8qqjsq

this is how I declare my view in the xml

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    <!-- tried res-auto didn't work -->
    xmlns:iconview="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/be.webelite.iconview"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/background_gray">

    <be.webelite.iconview.IconView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        iconview:icon_name="entypo_search"
        android:textSize="25dp"/>
```

attrs.xml in IconView>res>values directory

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <resources>
            <declare-styleable name="icon">
                <attr name="name" format="string" />
            </declare-styleable>

        </resources>
```

Comment: Can you post your complete build.gradle and describe a little bit more your project hierarchy ?

Comment: @Andros here are my gradle files http://pastie.org/private/h57o8nanydosq0dtm6eiq
and here is the folder structure http://pastie.org/private/nvbzomx2zeagdpzt8qqjsq

Comment: Can you post as well an example of your xml file in which your are using you custom view ?

Comment: @Andros I edited the question, added xml view

Comment: Post your attrs.xml  where you define your custom view attributes

Comment: @GeliteNight added it to the question

Comment: The `name="name"` attribute definition doesn't match the attribute used in the layout `"iconview:icon_name"="entypo_search"`. When you declare an attribute name, you need to use that same name in the layout and then use the same name when referencing it in code. Also, you'd generally use your class name in the styleable name (e.g. in `name="icon"` you'd use `IconView`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Can't really see what's wrong in your project. Here is how I use custom view & attrs in mine :

In my library project :

attrs.xml :

```
<declare-styleable name="CustomFontSize">
    <attr name="typeFace" format="string" />
</declare-styleable>
```

in my custom class :

```
 TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CustomFontSize);
 if (a == null) {
      return;
 }
 CharSequence s = a.getString(R.styleable.CustomFontSize_typeFace);
 if (s != null) {
    // do something
 }
```

In my Main Project here an example of one of my layout :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:paddingLeft="@dimen/border_margin_pulltorefresh"
              android:paddingRight="@dimen/border_margin_pulltorefresh"
              android:paddingBottom="@dimen/divider_height">


    <com.custom.view.TextViewFont
            style="@style/DateStyle"
            android:id="@+id/news_date"
            android:shadowColor="@color/white"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            custom:typeFace="@string/font_roboto_condensed_bold"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Hope it will help ...

**Edit :**

in my build.gradle of my "main project"

```
dependencies {
    compile project(":MyLibraryProject")
}
```

And here the build.gradle of my library :

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.7.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android-library'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.0.0'
    compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar'
    compile project(':WebediaCore:dependencies:DataDroid')
    compile project(':WebediaCore:dependencies:ViewPagerIndicator')
    compile project(':WebediaCore:dependencies:ActionBar-PullToRefresh')
    compile project(':WebediaCore:dependencies:Android-Universal-Image-Loader')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '19'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }
}
```

**EDIT1 :**

Try to use this namespace :

```
xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

and replace :

```
 iconview:icon_name="entypo_search"
```

by :

```
 custom:name="entypo_search"
```

Comment: Thank you, but are you using grub? how do you declare the library module inside the project?

Comment: When I use your exact same gradle.build for my library I get an error saying "main manifest missing" ...

Comment: It's because I use the default gradle project structure, so I don't need to declare the "sourceSets" in build.gradle . You can give it a shot, or put your sourceSet in build.gradle. The default project structure for gradle is describe here : http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Project-Structure

Comment: When I use res-auto I get this error "No resource identifier found for attribute 'icon_name' in package 'com.app.myapp'" but the iconview has a different package name "be.webelite.iconview" do you libararies have the same package name?

Comment: Yes my lib has a different package name. Please try with my last edit.

Comment: THIS WORKED ... still weird that gradle does this... thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

If you are grabbing attributes in your custom view's init method with hard references to that specific namespace then changing to res-auto will break that. Instead, you will need to change those references also to res-auto. Or the preferred method is to just grab the typed interface. For example, in my project this:

```
textStyle = attrs.getAttributeIntValue("http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.bodybuilding.mobile", "textStyle", 10);
shadowInner = attrs.getAttributeBooleanValue("http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.bodybuilding.mobile", "shadowInner", true);
shadowOuter = attrs.getAttributeBooleanValue("http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.bodybuilding.mobile", "shadowOuter", false);
allowResize = attrs.getAttributeBooleanValue("http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.bodybuilding.mobile", "allowResize", true);
```

Became either this:

```
textStyle = attrs.getAttributeIntValue("http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto", "textStyle", 10);
shadowInner = attrs.getAttributeBooleanValue("http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto", "shadowInner", true);
shadowOuter = attrs.getAttributeBooleanValue("http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto", "shadowOuter", false);
allowResize = attrs.getAttributeBooleanValue("http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto", "allowResize", true);
```

but preferably this:

```
TypedArray a = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.BBcomButton);
textStyle = a.getInt(R.styleable.BBcomButton_textStyle, 10);
shadowInner = a.getBoolean(R.styleable.BBcomButton_shadowInner, true);
shadowOuter = a.getBoolean(R.styleable.BBcomButton_shadowOuter, false);
shadowInnerColor = a.getColor(R.styleable.BBcomButton_shadowInnerColor, 0xff000000);
shadowOuterColor = a.getColor(R.styleable.BBcomButton_shadowOuterColor, 0xff000000);
allowResize = a.getBoolean(R.styleable.BBcomButton_allowResize, true);
```

To make it work

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use

```
iconview:name="entypo_search"
```

instead of

```
iconview:icon_name="entypo_search"
```

Comment: @mars use this  xmlns:iconview="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/be.webelite.iconview"

Comment: still null :s I think it's weird the same code works with old build method, but doesn't work with gradle? res-auto worked perfectly without gradle :s

Comment: @mars Really wired. But I use gradle and res-auto wroks fine.

Answer (score 2):

You will get this error when you have statically declared your package name as a namespace *(e.g xmlns:iconview="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/be.webelite.iconview" in your case)* in a layout file and try building the project with Lint on. Check the [Android Gradle Lint checks](https://sites.google.com/a/android.com/tools/tips/lint-checks):

> In Gradle projects, the actual package used in the final APK can vary; for
>   example,you can add a .debug package suffix in one version and not the other.
>   Therefore, you should not hardcode the application package in the resource;
>   instead, use the special namespace http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto
>   which will cause the tools to figure out the right namespace for the resource
>   regardless of the actual package used during the build.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is here and nothing appears to be working. From what I can see, having an underscore in your namespace appears to work fine in the editor, but breaks unexpectedly as you build the app.